# Remove sprite-HTML 5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I can't seem to remove a sprite from the HTML 5 canvas.

```
function collision_detect(a,b){
        if(Neither the enemy or the bullet exist){
    return;
    }else if(the bullet position is the same as the enemy position){
    console.log("Test")
             destroyed=true;
    }
    else
    {
    destroyed=false;
    }
}
```

The if/else statement works fine, "Test" is logged to the console every time a bullet collides with the enemy.

Here is where I am having a problem-in the game loop function.

```
if((enemy[x] !==null) && (destroyed===true)){
                enemy[x]=null;
                }
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: What do you mean "remove a sprite" ? The canvas has a bitmap model, you can clear it, draw over it, but you can't "remove" what you drew.

Comment: I mean remove the image from all of the code, as well as removing it from collision detection. There are also multiple images on the screen at once, however only one must be removed. Check it out [here](http://asteroidfield.eu5.org/test/index.html)  and you'll see what I mean. When you press a key, a missile if fired.

Comment: _“but you can't "remove" what you drew.”_ – well, there are methods such as `save` and `restore` which can be used for a kind of “undo” on the last operations …

Comment: The "remove sprite" is a red herring. He's likely redrawing the canvas every frame, otherwise nothing would move. So he really wants the enemy's sprite to not be considered during a draw if the enemy has since died.

Comment: Exactly @Matt Greer. Sorry for not explaining it well.